# Enable Chromedriver’s performance logging (Chrome and webview only) in Appium

Tags: performance, logging, selenium-webdriver, appium, selenium-chromedriver

Using Appium(AndroidDriver) to obtain performance logs from LogType, produces exception.
If you use a general RemoteWebDriver/ChromeDriver object, the performance logs are getting produced. While Appium also provides "enablePerformanceLogging" flag to capture performance logs for Android webview. But after enabling this flag also, performance logs are not getting captured.

Below code Produces performance logs using RemoteWebDriver/Chrome:

```
DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
if (null != androidPackage) {
    ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
    chromeOptions.setExperimentalOption("androidPackage", androidPackage);
    caps.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, chromeOptions);
}
LoggingPreferences logPrefs = new LoggingPreferences();
logPrefs.enable(LogType.BROWSER, Level.ALL);
logPrefs.enable(LogType.PERFORMANCE, Level.INFO);
caps.setCapability(CapabilityType.LOGGING_PREFS, logPrefs);

ChromeDriverService service = new ChromeDriverService.Builder()
        .usingDriverExecutable(new File("/Users/abc/Desktop/driver/chromedriver"))
        .usingAnyFreePort()
        .build();
service.start();
driver = new RemoteWebDriver(service.getUrl(),
        caps);
```

Check for available log types:

```
Logs logs = driver.manage().logs();
System.out.println("Log types: " + logs.getAvailableLogTypes());
```

O/P:

```
Log types: [performance, browser, driver, client]
```

Does NOT produce performance logs, using AndroidDriver(Appium):

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setCapability("browsername","chrome");
capabilities.setCapability("device","android");
capabilities.setCapability("deviceName","AndroidEmulator");
capabilities.setCapability("platformversion","5.1");
capabilities.setCapability("platformname","Android");
capabilities.setCapability("appPackage","com.android.chrome");
capabilities.setCapability("appActivity","com.google.android.apps.chrome.Main");
// Enabling LoggingPreferences
capabilities.setCapability("enablePerformanceLogging",true);

LoggingPreferences logPrefs = new LoggingPreferences();
logPrefs.enable(LogType.PERFORMANCE, Level.INFO);
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.LOGGING_PREFS, logPrefs);

driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
```

Check for available log types:

```
Logs logs = driver.manage().logs();
System.out.println("Log types: " + logs.getAvailableLogTypes());
```

O/P:

```
Log types: [logcat, client]
```

Execution of below line cause exception as performance log type not available:

```
List<LogEntry> entries = driverObj.manage().logs().get(LogType.PERFORMANCE).getAll();
```

exception thrown:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Unsupported log type performance. Supported types are {"logcat":"Logs for Android applications on real device and emulators via ADB"}
```

Help me to get/enable the performance for android webviews using Appium.

Answer (score 0):

```
desired_caps = {}
desired_caps['platformName'] = 'Android'
desired_caps['enablePerformanceLogging'] = True
driver = webdriver.Remote('http://localhost:9999/wd/hub', desired_caps)
```

Comment: You need to explain what does your code to do. It will be helpful for a user who is viewing your answer